# XSD key not in root element and complex keys

Tags: validation, xsd, key, complexity-theory

I searched for this, but can't find solution to my problem, so please don't trash this question.

We have a service with very complex XML configuration which is described by XSD. There are many rules that must be obeyed for things to run smoothly. XSD describes structure of configuration, but not the rules, which we must do now. After creating some global rules we have to do some more complex now and we encountered a problem. It seams like validator only uses key/keyref/unique from root element. I've created small XSD and XML file to illustrate that:

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://test.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://test.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:t="http://test.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Orders" type="t:OrdersList">
    <xs:key name="OrderNo">
      <xs:selector xpath="./t:Order" />
      <xs:field xpath="@Number" />
    </xs:key>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="OrdersList">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Order" nillable="false" type="t:Order" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Order">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Lines" nillable="false" type="t:OrdersLinesList" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Number" use="optional" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="ClientId" use="optional" type="xs:int" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="OrdersLinesList">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Line" nillable="false" type="t:OrderLine">
        <!-- THE PROBLEM -->
        <xs:key name="LineNoKey">
          <xs:selector xpath="./t:Line" />
          <xs:field xpath="@LineNumber" />
        </xs:key>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="OrderLine">
    <xs:attribute name="LineNumber" use="optional" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="ProductId" use="optional" type="xs:int" />
    <xs:attribute name="Amount" use="optional" type="xs:decimal" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Orders xmlns="http://test.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
  <Order Number="0001/5/13" ClientId="123">
    <Lines>
      <Line LineNumber="1" ProductId="123" Amount="4" />
      <Line LineNumber="2" ProductId="124" Amount="4" />
    </Lines>
  </Order>
  <Order Number="0002/5/13" ClientId="123">
    <Lines>
      <Line LineNumber="1" ProductId="123" Amount="4" />
      <!-- Duplicate number - it DOES validate as expected. -->
      <Line LineNumber="1" ProductId="124" Amount="4" />
    </Lines>
  </Order>
  <!-- Duplicate number - it doesn't validate as expected. -->
  <Order Number="0002/5/13" ClientId="123">
    <Lines>
      <Line LineNumber="1" ProductId="123" Amount="4" />
      <Line LineNumber="2" ProductId="124" Amount="4" />
    </Lines>
  </Order>
</Orders>
```

I have a few questions which I can't find any sensible answer:

1. How to solve the above. LineNumber must be unique, but only within Order/Lines.
2. Is it possible to allow keyref to contain non existing virtual value (our service uses some predefined... let say things. Custom ones are defined in XML to allow extending functionality, but in most of the cases, users will use predefined ones)
3. Is there any way to determine if list of elements within a tag (something like Lines above) has at least one tag with attribute set to certain value. Good example would be to describe it like a list of tables with unique names, that has list of columns with unique names and at least one of the columns is a primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the corrected constraint for Lines/Line:

```
<xs:complexType name="Order">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Lines" nillable="false" type="t:OrdersLinesList">
            <!-- THE PROBLEM SOLVED -->
            <xs:key name="LineNoKey">
                <xs:selector xpath="t:Line"/>
                <xs:field xpath="@LineNumber"/>
            </xs:key>               
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Number" use="optional" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="ClientId" use="optional" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

If always helps if you can visualize your constraints, to understand the scope they act upon:

The correct diagram:

[image]

vs. the original one:

[image]

You can see that the selector rooted in the element **Line** is looking for yet another Line (**./t:Line**); and even if you fix the selector, it'll always match at most one attribute. The idea of a key is that the selector should match **a set of nodes** among which the *field* must be present and unique.

The above should take care of 1.

2. No.
3. Not based on an attribute. To stick with your parallel, for XSD 1.0 I would probably enforce an element called **PrimaryKey**, which should contain one or more references to names of the other columns; as if instead of using the PRIMARY KEY constraint clause in a column definition, I would enforce the use of the same at the table level.

Comment: Thank's man... I didn't thought about that... What software did you used to visualize this?